# Problems Updating View with Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I am having some trouble updating my `secondViewController` view in Xcode using Swift 5. I want my app to add two numbers together and show the result in the second ViewController. Although it works the first time, if I return to my previous view and change the numbers, the view does not update.

I tried using `viewWillAppear`, `viewWillDisappear`, amongst others, including `NSNotificationCenter` `addObserve`, but I have had no luck whatsoever.

Do you have any recommendations? Am I missing something?

Please see below for the code and a screenshot of my ViewControllers:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//

import UIKit

var result = ""
var resultFinal = Float(result)
let finalResult = resultFinal!

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var firstNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondNumber: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func getResult()-> Float{

        guard let fNumber = firstNumber.text else {
            return 0
        }

        let firstFloat = Float(fNumber)

        guard let sNumber = secondNumber.text else {
            return 0
        }

        let secondFloat = Float(sNumber)

        let sumNumber: Float = firstFloat! + secondFloat!

        return sumNumber
    }


    @IBAction func submitSum(_ sender: Any) {
        resultFinal = getResult()
        print(resultFinal!)

    }


}

//
//  secondViewController.swift
//


import UIKit

class secondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var test: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.test.text!=""

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        test.text = String(finalResult)
    }

}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the global variables. It seems from your code that you expect these three to reevaluate every time one of them changes:

```
var result = ""
var resultFinal = Float(result)
let finalResult = resultFinal!
```

For example, if you set `resultFinal = 4`, then `finalResult` will equal `4`. However, those variables only evaluate once––the first time. You can simplify your use of these variables significantly. Replace these three with:

```
var result: Float?
```

Then, in `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondNumber: UITextField!

    func getResult() -> Float {
        guard let number1 = Float(firstNumber.text ?? "0") ?? 0
        guard let number2 = Float(secondNumber.text ?? "0") ?? 0
        return number1 + number2
    }

    @IBAction func submitSum(_ sender: Any) {
        result = getResult()
    }

}
```

**Note:** I simplified `getResult` and made it treat empty fields as 0.

In `SecondViewController`:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var test: UITextField!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        test.text = String(result ?? 0)
    }

}
```

**Note:** `self.test.text!=""` doesn't really do anything, so I removed it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked very well. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @JesusZamora, glad to help. If you don’t have any more questions on this topic, hit the check mark to accept this answer.